# I am trying to use a regular expression validation to check for only numeric values. Value should be between 0 to 99 and in whole number

Tags: regex, validation

I am trying to use a regular expression validation to check for only numeric values. The value should be between 0 to 99 and in the whole number. It should not be allowed 00 as a value, Single 0 is allowed. How can I make this?

Answer (score -1):

> Try this: \b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\b

Regex for 0-99

The regular expression for range 0 to 99 is

\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])\b

This range is divided in to two ranges

1. 0 to 9 --> [0-9]
2. 10 to 99 --> [1-9][0-9]

> Source:
> https://regextutorial.org/regex-for-numbers-and-ranges.php
> For testing:
> https://regex101.com/

> 

Comment: Please don't answer questions which exhibit no effort or research; we don't want to encourage them.